# Update List Item with Workflow and Calcuation

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I have List A that contains 2 fields with number values, i.e. **INDUNITS** and **FAMUNITS** I need these fields to be READ-ONLY.

I have List B that collects so information and needs to "Update" the value of the 2 fields in List A.

What I would like to do is trigger a Workflow after a item is created in List B to add the current value of each field with the value of List B, then update the fields in List A to reflect the new values.

My issue is I don't know how to get the current values in List A into a Workflow in List B and add them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SharePoint Online workflow set up these steps:

- Use the "Set Workflow Variable" activity, call your variable `indunits_a`. Set the "value" portion of this activity to the value of the item in List A. You will need to know the name of the list, i.e. List A, the name of the field i.e. `INDUNITS`, and the ID of the item in List A.
- Use the same activity again to set another workflow variable, `famunits_a`, to the value of `FAMUNITS` from List A
- Use the same activity again to set another workflow variable, `indunits_b`, to the value of `INDUNITS` from List B
- Use the same activity again to set another workflow variable, `famunits_b`, to the value of `FAMUNITS` from List B
- Use the "Do Calculation" activity to add `indunits_a` and `indunits_b`, outputting to another workflow variable, `indunits_new`
- Use the same activity to add `famunits_a` and `famunits_b`, outputting to another workflow variable, `famunits_new`
- Use the "Update List Item" activity to update the values of `INDUNITS` and `FAMUNITS` in List A with `indunits_new` and `famunits_new`